# how to process the recycleView can't show completely

Tags: android

My project's structure is as the  picture describe. It include two parts. The first part is the  header,  it contains a `viewPager`(used to  display Advertisement) and a `Tablayout`. The second part is also a `viewpager`,in the  `viewpager` there are four fragments.

I put a `recycleView` which has a function of loadmore in every fragments. Now i meet a problem that when i scroll the `recycleView` by the fling way. The smooth can't be serial.

so i  used the open-source library **smoothappbarlayout**    in the github and `CoordinatorLayout`. In the `smoothappbarlayout` demo, i replace the toolbar with a `viewpager`,then it  cause the problem   which the `recycleView` can't show completely.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be with your **FrameLayout** that you are using as the container for your fragments.

Remove:

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and add `false`

or

`android:clipToPadding="true"` and add `false`.

If still you face any problem post the codes that you have used, i will help you resolving the bug.

Comment: i have try your answer ,but  it does't  have effect .now i  have  sloved  the problem.  thanks all the same.